# Rollup.js: Any Way to Reproduce Babel Module Resolver (eg. ~/foo => src/foo)

Tags: rollupjs

I've been using Webpack/Babel for awhile, and as part of that setup I use the Babel module resolver plugin so that I can do:

```
import foo from '~/somePath';
```

and have it get converted into:

```
import foo from 'PROJECT_HOME/somePath';
```

However, I'm now trying to switch to Rollup, which supports Babel but not Babel module resolvers.  So, my question is, is there any way to simulate the `~/` => `PROJECT_HOME/` functionality in Rollup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like [`rollup-plugin-alias`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-alias) could do that for you.